# Making a quest generator by trying to emulate Do-while loop with recursion

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, do-while

**Trying to make do-while loop in prolog with recursion in order to sort information. Need help progressing and making loop work.**

**If I have to use lists, information on how to go about that would be deeply appreciated.**

So I am trying to make a quest generator with prolog but I am very unfamiliar with the language. I know conceptually what I want to do, but have no idea on how to actually do it.

I want to generate and print a set of quests that come from at least 2 quest groups and result in at least 3000 exp. My plan was to divide by quest type, then recursively write the new quest name until the sum of exp would be reached. (basically emulating a do while loop)

I just dont know how to formulate the initial recursive statements.

```
questsA(qName,exp) :-allQuests(qName,A,exp).
questsB(qName,exp) :-allQuests(qName,B,exp).
questsC(qName,exp) :-allQuests(qName,C,exp).

different(X,X):- !, fail.
different(_,_).

Recur(3000,X,Y,Z):- \\not sure what to put or how to get here

Recur(0,gName1,C,):-
    allQuests(qName,C,exp),
    Write(qName),
    nl,
    Recur(exp,gName,C,exp).
Recur(N,gName,C,exp):-
    allQuests(gName1,Y,Z),
    different(C,Y),
    write(gName),
    nl,
    N is N+Z,
    Recur(N,gname,4,Z).
```

I dont know how to put in a tester so i don't get repeated quests in the same recursive loop, and I would like to avoid using the repeat() predicate. 
I am pretty sure that I can just do this all with lists, but I don't for the life of me know how or where to start.

For an example of my desired output:
if my database is:

```
allquest('water for village','Main quest', 2000). 
allquest('get book for elder','fetch quest',1000). 
allquests('kill 20 birds', 'bounty quest', 1000).
```

The output would be

```
?-'water for village', 'get book for elder'
?-;'water for village','kill 20 birds'
```

Comment: You got variables in Prolog, so I don't know why exactly you miss them. If you wrote down the algorithm in some kind of procedural pseudo-code it might be easier to help: at the moment, I really struggle with understanding what you are trying to achieve. An example of what you want to query and what results you expect might help, too.

Comment: "but I am very unfamiliar with the language" usually, reading through a tutorial or a book helps.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to sort through my quests for a set of quests that come from at least 2 categories and whose experience total is more than a minimum amount. my database would be stuff like allquest('water for village','Main quest', 2000). allquest('get book for elder','fetch quest',1000). allquests('kill 20 birds', 'bounty quest', 1000).

Comment: cont: quest', 1000). The output would be 'water for village', 'get book for elder';'water for village','kill 20 birds'. I wanted to try to simulate a while loop in order to parse through the clause and write the next element in my desired output every time by using a recursive loop to simulate a while loop.

Comment: learning to walk by smallest steps is easier than trying to jump or run right from the start. i.e. try to ask simpler, more focused and more specific question, about as small a code fragment as possible, one problem at a time; not all jumbled up together. try to read your question imagining you don't know what it's about and see if you could understand it. (I couldn't, sorry). try not to use pronouns at all. instead of "it" or "whose", just put in full names, no matter the repetitions. "elegance cobbler tailor" - google it. :)